# ASP.Net machinekey support for PBKDF2

Tags: web-config, membership-provider, pbkdf2

Does anyone know if it is possible to wrap the [MS PBKDF2 implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) in a [KeyedHashAlgorithm class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.keyedhashalgorithm.aspx), in order to use it from a machinekey section in web.config? If so, how is that accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Zeletic wrote a [great article](http://zetetic.net/blog/2012/3/29/strong-password-hashing-for-aspnet.html) on how to do this.

Comment: It's good that Zeletic have written a NuGet package for this, but the requirement for the GAC rules it out of an awful lot of .Net installs.